# How to view Exchange Server mail flow and other reports?

Tags: exchange

When I request a report in the Exchange Admin Center (on-line), it says it will email me the report.
But, the reason I am requesting a report is that email is not working!
Is there a way to view the report through the website? Alternatively, is there a way to view mail logs without generating a report?
[image: Your report will be emailed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use PowerShell with Get-MessageTrace and related cmdlets, it allows you to filter more. And testconnectivity.com is also helpful.

https://4sysops.com/archives/tracing-emails-in-microsoft-365-with-powershell/

Comment: Thank you. The PowerShell Get-MessageTrace function allowed me to diagnose and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could users receive the internal or external emails successfully?
According to my test, the request a report will take some time to email you(It would take 30-60 minutes).

You could also view the report in the new EAC at https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com, go to Reports > Mail flow > and then select Exchange transport rule report on the Mail flow reports page.

To go directly to the report, open https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/reports/transportruledetails.

Comment: We use Exchange server only in conjunction with Microsoft Teams. All emails are supposed to be forwarded to our corporate mail server. The issue I am trying to diagnose is that emails generated by Microsoft Teams are not being forwarded, although they were in the past. Nor are the reports from Exchange itself.